# Can I make a LiveUSB from a LiveUSB?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, startup-disk-creator

I often upgrade to a new release of Ubuntu, think I could have got some malware and then have to use my LiveUSB to install a fresh install, however the LiveUSB is using an old version, so I was wondering if it possible to boot from a LiveUSB in order to download an Ubuntu ISO and then use the Startup Disk Creator to make another LiveUSB? So I would boot from one in order to make another.

Is this possible or could there be any problems with doing this? The version of Ubuntu on my LiveUSB is Ubuntu GNOME 15.04, it's just that if I get infected with something I don't want to keep carry on installing an old version and then having to upgrade again, I would prefer just to create a LiveUSB with the latest version, however I have to be sure that my system is clean otherwise I could infect the new LiveUSB.

**Clarification:**

15.04 is currently the latest stable release, however soon 15.10 will be released and I will upgrade to it, however if once I have upgraded I get a virus or something then I will have to do a fresh install of 15.04 and then upgrade again, what I would much prefer to do is to install a fresh install of 15.10 when it comes out, but make sure that it could not have anything injected into it.

Comment: you want to start a live system, download a iso down and create a new boot media?

Comment: @A.B.: Yes, and I'm just wanting to know if this can be done without any problems. Because I don't know how my LiveUSB would feel about creating another of its kind... Who knows, it might even get a bit jealous! :P

Comment: The more interesting question would be how to *overwrite* the current live usb stick with a new image, i.e. **How to update a live image**. What do you think?

Comment: @ByteCommander: Yes, I have actually been thinking about that myself... I didn't ask because I thought the possibility was low, but as you suggested it I have decided to ask anyway: https://askubuntu.com/questions/681793/how-to-upgrade-current-liveusb-image-when-booting-from-it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can do that as long as you have enough space for the new ISO. But honestly, I think that is quite paranoid. **;)**

And believe me, your live system that does not matter. Otherwise it would not be genuine and therefore a bad live system.

Answer (score 0):

#### Face it!

**You need to start making nightly [system back-ups](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) on non-rewritable media (BlueRay?) and then restore your entire system to whatever it was before the infection.**

On the other hand: One day you'll be a great security researcher as mal-ware seems to keep hunting you down, so you'll always be the first one to research the latest nastiness...

## ;-)

Comment: Yes, research it, and then accidentally download it! **:P**

Comment: Too bad I threw away all my votes of today for bashing the "Late Answer" review queue... :P

Comment: @ByteCommander: D tomorrow's another day!